# Prototype Event.observe(window, 'change', function() - Not working in IE Browser

Tags: prototypejs

Prototype, Event.observer 'window' 'change' is not working in IE browser /its working fine in Mozilla,chrome browser. Can you any one give the solution for this? 
Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Event.observe(window, 'change', function() {
alert("Loaded!");
var opt0=document.getElementsByTagName("option")[0];
var opt1=document.getElementsByTagName("option")[1];   
var opt2=document.getElementsByTagName("option")[2];   
var opt3=document.getElementsByTagName("option")[3];
var opt4=document.getElementsByTagName("option")[4];   

   if(opt0.selected==true || opt4.selected==true) {
      document.getElementById("chgButton").style.marginLeft="0em";
   }

   if(opt1.selected==true) {
      document.getElementById("chgButton").style.marginLeft="4em";
   }

   if(opt2.selected==true) {
      document.getElementById("chgButton").style.marginLeft="8em";
   }

   if(opt3.selected==true) {
      document.getElementById("chgButton").style.marginLeft="12em";
   }

// some more code down here, but even without it it doesn't work!
});     
</script>

<div> 
<div style="float:left;">
    <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>

    </select>
    <div style="float:right;"> 
    <input type="button" value="submit" id="chgButton"/>
    </div>

</div>

</div>
```

Thanks in advance
ps

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect to happen? If you're trying to use event bubbling then you might have better luck with `document` or `document.body` or something much more specific like the form element that contains those inputs.